# What is the best practice for storing a variable for use in different forms?

Tags: c#, .net

What's the best practice for holding a variable from startup for use in later forms?

For example, I have a username I need to store for logging if they made any changes to records. The application has multiple forms and it doesn't seem practical to keep passing it back and forth.

Comment: You could use a Singleton or MonoState.

Comment: While it's often nesscessary please take a look at this question before implementing any global variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil/7027536#7027536

Comment: I tend to favour an instance method

Answer (score 2):

You can keep these variables as static members anywhere in your assembly and use them anywhere, without having to use a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx), or else, use something like a static configuration class, but if you really want to get this right, I would recommend a user related session object, that could be returned using a singleton just like Pierre said.

**UPDATE**

Someone who did not seem to read the whole post downvoted my answer, so I thought I should clarify it a bit more. There are no issues in using static variables if you know what you're doing and that applies to everything, but in this case I even said that I would use a non-static user related object, so I hope the OP does a wise choice.

Comment: down voting as static members used without careful consideration can cause issues later on - see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil/7027536#7027536

Comment: Your downvote was rather pathetic because I pointed out the right way of doing that. And being a Java/C# developer since 2001 I know the "dangerous" or using static members. Write something constructive instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the current infrastructure available to you such as Properties.Settings.Default which is a singleton by the way ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using anything static quite easily. First think, when are these variables going to be needed, and, who(or what) is going to need them ? 
Could you not use a class that contains them, and instanciate it once, and share it between the objects that need it ?

If it really is required everywhere, and "should" be static, then maybe make it static in some helper class.